# check circleci's docker container memory usage

Tags: docker, circleci

I am building and testing code through circleci on github. As shown below, docker executor is specified and used for testing.

```
// in .circleci/config.yml
executors:
  test_executor:
    docker:
      - image: circleci-base/java:corretto
      - image: postgres image
      - image: other image
      - image: other image

...
jobs:
  test:
    executor: test_executor
    steps:
      - run: // for build
      - run: // for test
```

It works fine, but I would like to track the memory usage of the containers being used. As one of circleci's test results, CPU and memory metrics are provided in the 'RESOURCES' tab, but usage for each container is not provided.

As shown below, a command to view Docker's indicators was added as part of the step, but the Docker command itself is not recognized.

```
  - setup_remote_docker // not work whether set this setting or not.
  - run:
      name: docker stats
      command: |
        while true; do
          sleep 5
          docker stats --no-stream
          echo "======"
        done
      background: true
```

> /bin/bash: line 2: docker: command not found Exited with code exit
> status 127

I was wondering if there was a way to track the memory usage of a running container.

Answer (score -1):

To check CircleCI's Docker container memory usage, you can use the following steps:

1. Log in to your CircleCI account and navigate to the specific project or build you want to monitor.
2. Go to the "Jobs" section of your project or build page.
3. Find the job that is running inside a Docker container and click on it to view its details.
4. Look for the "Memory Usage" section within the job details page. This section will provide information about how much memory is being used by the Docker container during execution.
5. The memory usage information may include metrics such as total memory allocated, current memory usage, and any limits set for the container.

Please note that depending on your CircleCI configuration and setup, this information may vary slightly. If you are unable to find or interpret the memory usage details, it is recommended to contact a CircleCI support agent at support@circleci.com for further assistance tailored specifically to your situation.

References: https://circleci.com/docs/java-oom/